# Build app.. and then i get this?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Well, i opened my project today, went to build my app again after making 1 or 2 small changes, and i get this:

> Application failed codesign
>   verification.  The signature was
>   invalid, or it was not signed with an
>   Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is this for app store submission, or just a regular everyday build?

Comment: Has anything expired overnight? E.g. a provisioning profile?

Comment: Nothing has expired overnight. It's a regular build.

Answer (score 0):

check your project (and target) settings, which developer profile is used. You probably have install a new developer profile and this project still use an old one.

Comment: Both say the same thing - the latest developer profile. No settings have been changed since i did this yesterday.

Comment: have you also checked your different targets (XCode3). Maybe a clean all targets will help (Cmd-Shift-K)

Comment: Done that, to no avail. It was working yesterday. Then i open it today and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

check certificate in  keychain access and provisioning profile code_sign_identity need consistent.